# Is the 2048 question really on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Somehow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342854/what-is-the-optimal-algorithm-for-the-game-2048) survived the community filtering (due to its popularity I assume). In my opinion it's a good example of a too broad question (and it's also poorly phrased, and none of the answers actually claims to be "optimal").

Now we have numerous questions where people use the fact that it was left open as a justification to post their somewhat related questions, for example:

- [What is the optimal blind algorithm for the game, 2048?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748313/what-is-the-optimal-blind-algorithm-for-the-game-2048)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748601/strategy-for-2048-clone

Is the original question really on-topic on Stack Overflow or should we close it?

Comment: You mean you'd like to have the popular == evil argument again?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Not at all, but I don't see how the original thread is a fit for Stack Overflow (the reason why it was closed in the first place)

Comment: I'm sorry Niklas, but there's thousands of algorithm questions out there that are a lot broader and less well specified than this one. You've noticed this one because it's popular, easy to understand and has a pretty answer; these aren't detrimental attributes. I just don't understand the community's fixation with deleting the popular algorithm questions and leaving the utter crud.

Comment: ... you do realize that question has been closed twice, and reopened twice, right?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I'm pretty familiar with the [algorithm] questions, and I've not seen one that is *this* broad and still survived. Example?

Comment: @hichris123 Yes I do, but why was it reopened?

Comment: Ah, you're one of the origional close voters of that question. Makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: +1 to this being an outlier on the [algorithm] tag, irrespective of popularity.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards And no, I've seen this question already 2 minutes after it was posted and even then it was clear that it's much too broad and underspecified. Afterwards OP edited in a pretty much useless algorithm to make it more programming-related I guess

Comment: I'm cheating on the first one slightly but here you go... it was actually more difficult than I remembered when I last looked so I guess someone's been having a positive impact: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748139/cloud-computing-vs-typical-distributed-systems, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283270/how-to-determine-whether-my-calculation-of-pi-is-accurate,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721759/best-algorithm-data-structure-for-a-continually-updated-priority-queue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547537/is-there-a-better-algorithm-for-this-werewolf-prob

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I close-voted #1. Not sure where the cavalry is. #2 is old. #3 is narrowed by the comment thread, which should be edited into the question text. #4 is fine because they aren't very many good ways to do it (pretty much just shortest paths of some ilk).

Comment: You're going down the question is validated by its answers route then @David? Aside from the first one the others are all pretty identical. Some problem statement, a vague attempt at solving it and a request for something "better". I guess I just don't understand the difference.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards You're arguing pretty much to the point that those are technically not really on-topic. So we justify having bad questions by the fact that there are other bad questions left unclosed?

Comment: No @Niklas, I'm stating that I don't understand why people always go after the popular ones when there's as bad and worse out there, that's all.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat huh?

Comment: I'm not arguing @David. My statement, in my first comment, is that I don't understand why the community goes after the popular questions.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I can't speak for the community. I close-vote stuff that deserves it when I'm not feeling as though it's an exercise in futility. The popular questions are the only ones that get reopened, which is why we have these conversations only about the popular ones.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards In addition to what David said, the popular ones are used as a justification and "inspiration" for others

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards To respond to your previous comment, yes, I do think that questions should be judged in part by their possible answers (and also a little by some "meta" considerations about whether it's an actual problem). The 2048 questions are part of a class that includes comparatively unpopular questions, defined by the simultaneous (i) presence of many possible low-hanging fruit answers (as opposed to one obvious greedy or brute-force algorithm) and (ii) absence of a "final" answer. These questions IMHO are too much like a research agenda to be a good fit for SO.

Comment: It seems to me, @benisuǝqbackwards, that -- assuming that one sincerely believes that a question is detrimental to the site -- the urgency of handling it is directly proportinate to its popularity, not inversely.

Answer (score 29):

I don't see why this particular subject should be treated differently from others.

If the question asked is different enough from that original, popular question then it should be left open.
If it's worthy of a duplicate then you close it.
If it's doesn't meet the criteria for a good question, then you close it.

Your edits changed your question's meaning quite a bit, so let's address that as well: yes, the original thread is on-topic.

An optimal algorithm is not a subjective manner: it is something you can measure and it is finite. The question is clearly worded and shows an initial implementation of the problem at hand.

People that follow the [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) tag will know that these questions tend to be more general usually and even that is not the case here.

I see no problem with leaving this question open as it is.

Comment: My point was rather that the original thread itself is not necessarily a good fit for SO (rather than being too broad). Clarified the question

Comment: I have rarely seen *such* a broad question on [algorithm] and I've seen almost all questions during the last 2 months and answered a lot of them.

Comment: Could you lay out your arguments that show why it is too broad exactly?

Comment: Because it has "too many possible answers" and "good answers are very long", as evidenced by the answers themselves?

Comment: Are they actually to long, or are you distracted by the large screen shots?

Comment: I wouldn't consider the explanation of an approach "too long"; that reason is used when someone basically requires an introduction to an entire subject. Aside from that: the answers really aren't that long. There will often be a lot of possible answers for *algorithm* questions but all together this question isn't extraordinary: 8 positive answers and 1 negative, that's not too much for a question with 300K views.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel From my experience with [algorithm], there's usually only a very restricted set of possible "good" answers that fundamentally differ in their approach. You can easily enforce that set by specifying some upper bound in your question. Failing to do that indeed usually results in the question being close-voted for "lack of sufficient information", "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad".

Comment: "An optimal algorithm is not a subjective manner" Neither is a shortest program, but Code Golf got forked anyway. The 2048 questions (and others that are not so popular) have a golf-y "feel" that I would like to see less of on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree that my question was underspecified as originally stated and have modified it to be far more specific.  I specify a blind algorithm that that achieves 4.5-fold performance over random play, and ask whether there is a better one in a specific sense (consistently higher mean score in 10^6 trials).  I now also ask that people only post algorithms that they have validated as meeting this criteria.  This is more specific than the original 2048 question, and surely not a duplicate but rather of some practical value to those who want to play as humans but get off to a fast start.